# XAudio2: how to convert seconds to samples

Tags: xaudio2

in the Xaudio2 API you can specify the start and endposition only in samples.

but i require them to be set by seconds.

now i am looking for a way to convert seconds into samples but havent found much information on how to do that so far.

any help on this is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you created your mastering voice, you set the input sample rate. This number is the amount of samples per second.

Multiply the time you want to seek to by the sample rate, and you get the sample you want to seek to.

For example, if the sample rate is 44100, and you want to seek to second 20.4, the sample you want to seek to is

```
44100 * 20.4 = 899640
```

Check the reference for [CreateMasteringVoice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh405048%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more information

There's also some more information regarding [Sample Rate Conversions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee415817%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in XAudio2.

Comment: thanks! dont i have to take into account if its stereo/mono? i.e.e divide by 2 if its stereo.

Comment: Sampling rate is independent of the amount of channels, so you don't divide by 2. If you had to seek using bytes instead of samples, you would multiply by the amount of channels, and then by the sample size in bytes (usually 2 bytes, but can also be 1, 3, 4 and even 8)

Comment: @clamp are you still having problems with this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that converts samples to milliseconds (which avoids the need to use floating point)

```
size_t SoundEffect::GetSampleDurationMS() const
{
    if ( !pImpl->mWaveFormat || !pImpl->mWaveFormat->nSamplesPerSec )
        return 0;

    uint64_t samples = GetSampleDuration();
    return static_cast<size_t>( ( samples * 1000 ) / pImpl->mWaveFormat->nSamplesPerSec );
}
```

Here `pImpl->mWaveFormat` is a `const WAVEFORMATEX*`

`GetSampleDuration()` returns the duration of a wave in samples, which is actually a little tricky for formats other than PCM:

```
size_t SoundEffect::GetSampleDuration() const
{
    if ( !pImpl->mWaveFormat || !pImpl->mWaveFormat->nChannels )
        return 0;

    switch( GetFormatTag( pImpl->mWaveFormat ) )
    {
    case WAVE_FORMAT_ADPCM:
        {
            auto adpcmFmt = reinterpret_cast<const ADPCMWAVEFORMAT*>( pImpl->mWaveFormat ); 

            uint64_t duration = uint64_t( pImpl->mAudioBytes / adpcmFmt->wfx.nBlockAlign ) * adpcmFmt->wSamplesPerBlock;
            int partial = pImpl->mAudioBytes % adpcmFmt->wfx.nBlockAlign;
            if ( partial )
            {
                if ( partial >= ( 7 * adpcmFmt->wfx.nChannels ) )
                    duration += ( partial * 2 / adpcmFmt->wfx.nChannels - 12 );
            }
            return static_cast<size_t>( duration );
        }

#if defined(_XBOX_ONE) || (_WIN32_WINNT < _WIN32_WINNT_WIN8)

    case WAVE_FORMAT_WMAUDIO2:
    case WAVE_FORMAT_WMAUDIO3:
        if ( pImpl->mSeekTable && pImpl->mSeekCount > 0 )
        {
            return pImpl->mSeekTable[ pImpl->mSeekCount - 1 ] / uint32_t( 2 * pImpl->mWaveFormat->nChannels );
        }
        break;

#endif

#if defined(_XBOX_ONE) && defined(_TITLE)

    case WAVE_FORMAT_XMA2:
        return reinterpret_cast<const XMA2WAVEFORMATEX*>( pImpl->mWaveFormat )->SamplesEncoded;

#endif

    default:
        if ( pImpl->mWaveFormat->wBitsPerSample > 0 )
        {
            return static_cast<size_t>( ( uint64_t( pImpl->mAudioBytes ) * 8 )
                                        / uint64_t( pImpl->mWaveFormat->wBitsPerSample * pImpl->mWaveFormat->nChannels ) );
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

`GetFormatTag()` is a helper that handles both WAVEFORMATEX and WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE formats.

```
inline uint32_t GetFormatTag( const WAVEFORMATEX* wfx )
{
    if ( wfx->wFormatTag == WAVE_FORMAT_EXTENSIBLE )
    {
        if ( wfx->cbSize < ( sizeof(WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE) - sizeof(WAVEFORMATEX) ) )
            return 0;

        static const GUID s_wfexBase = {0x00000000, 0x0000, 0x0010, 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0xAA, 0x00, 0x38, 0x9B, 0x71};

        auto wfex = reinterpret_cast<const WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE*>( wfx );

        if ( memcmp( reinterpret_cast<const BYTE*>(&wfex->SubFormat) + sizeof(DWORD),
                     reinterpret_cast<const BYTE*>(&s_wfexBase) + sizeof(DWORD), sizeof(GUID) - sizeof(DWORD) ) != 0 )
        {
            return 0;
        }

        return wfex->SubFormat.Data1;
    }
    else
    {
        return wfx->wFormatTag;
    }
}
```

All code snippets are from [DirectXTK for Audio](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929).